# text-shadow and box-shadow while printing (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing-web-page

I'm making some printable calendar website using HTML, CSS and JS.

Unfortunately I cannot use CSS property called `text-shadow`, because shadow behind text prints as solid black text without any blur or transparency.

Same problem occurs when I'm trying to use `box-shadow` for any div - shadow prints like solid black color with no transparency.

I'm using Chrome with style `html {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;}` to ensure all background colors will be printed.

Any workaround? I would prefer not to use any background image.

Edit:
I don't want to hide shadows, it's very easy of course. I want to have shadows printed correctly.

Comment: Best bet would probably be to remove the text/box shadows in your print stylesheet.

Comment: Of course I can do that, but I want to have them on my printout. Sorry if I didn't express enough clear

Comment: Hmmm, folks are usually wanting to remove them, so I had the same thought as @BillyMoat. This might be a limitation of print drivers, etc...but I'll be curious to see if anyone knows more.

Comment: Yes, printer limitations seems to be one possibility, but maybe there is some "magic" attribute to enable printing those shadows.

Comment: Assuming you hit a dead-end with text-shadow printing, you could generate an image from the HTML on the server-side since printing an image should be fine. Of course, that's a lot of work for an effect ;-)

Answer (score 29):

I realise this is an old question, but just to note that it is possible to make shadows print correctly in Chrome. You need to set both `-webkit-print-color-adjust` and a filter, as found in this bug thread: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174583

```
.thing {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
    -webkit-filter:opacity(1);
}
```

(I prefer to set opacity rather than `blur` as used in the bug, simply because it seems likely to cause fewer problems).

Note that this will limit the resolution of the print (filter makes it send a rasterised version), so text might become harder to read. If you really want to work around that, I'd suggest duplicating the div (one for the shadow, with the filter hack and transparent text, and another for the text with no shadow)

Comment: Wow this is an awful bug... Shadowed header becomes unusably low quality

Comment: Apparently it also changes shadow color to the color of the text.

Comment: As of Chrome 46 adding a filter causes the text to be horribly pixelated. There is no current workaround for this in Chrome as far as I am aware

Comment: @davidelrizzo yes that was the case when I found this too. It's a pity, but see my last paragraph for a possible workaround in some situations.

Comment: I have the same problem today.. what will be the answear today? this won´t work for me!

Comment: See my answer below for how to avoid rasterizing the content of the element when it's printed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57714709/200508)

Comment: `-webkit-filter:opacity(1);` causes links not clickable on PDFs for unknow reason. I changed it to `-webkit-filter: blur(0);` and everything works fine.

Comment: Using `-webkit-filter: blur(0);` and `text-shadow: none;` (to help get rid of blurred text) together with @Dave's answer is what worked best for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
@media print {
  .item {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px #ccc);
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ccc;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dave's fix did not work for me, this one does. Apparently the bug will finally be fixed in version 61 of Chrome.

Comment: I am on version 62, this is still a problem, and this fix also did not work.

Comment: This lets my chrome go for a preview load up forever.

Answer (score 2):

I used all the possible solutions to this but the border shadow(with stepped gradient) would show up on my page, but **not** when I do a Ctrl+P on the page and either- print the page or save as PDF. I even used-

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
-webkit-filter:opacity(1);
```

I do the same Ctrl+P on this page- https://css-tricks.com/examples/BodyBorder/kottke.php and it works fine.

**Solution**: I had to remove the bootstrap.css included at the top of my page for the border shadow to show up on my PDF, or when I print the page.

```
<link href="/lib/bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Comment: this worked for me, but why is that that bootstrap causing it?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for a way to avoid rasterizing the content of the element with a `box-shadow`, this is what I used (extended from @Dave's answer):

```
.thing {
    position: relative;
}

.thing::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: /* define your shadow here, not in .thing */;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
}
```

This creates a pseudo-element at the beginning of the element you want to have a shadow. The pseudo-element is sized the same as the parent and then the drop shadow is applied to it only. That way, the drop shadow can be rasterized while the rest of the content of the parent is not.

There are a few issues if you have borders, if your element doesn't support children, etc. but this works in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
html {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
}
```

**But it causes links on PDF non-clickable for unknown reason.**

After I change it to the css below, both shadow and link problems are solved.

```
.thing {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
```

Comment: Can confirm that this solved the issue in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to compromise your web page to make it look pretty printed. Simply define a `print.css` that makes the printed view suit your needs.

```
# index.html
<head>
  <link href="/css/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>

# print.css
.shadow {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

For more, Smashing Magazine has a helpful article on [How To Set Up A Print Style Sheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).